# The limit of a sequence based on upper/lower bounds restriction

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, inequality

Let $t>0$ and For any positive integer $K$ let $q_j$ be such that $ \frac{t}{j}>q_j > \frac{t}{j+1}$ for all $1 \leq j \leq K$ and $t- j q_j = q_{j+1}$ for $1 \leq j < K$, these inequalities will restrict the interval in which we can choose $q_1$ from,

For Example :

$K=1$ gives $t>q_1 >\frac{t}{2}$

$K=2$ gives $ t>q_1 >\frac{t}{2}  $ && $\frac{t}{2} > q_2 > \frac{t}{3} $ and $ q_2 = t-q_1 $ which when solving for $q_1$ gives that $ \frac{2t}{3} > q_1 > \frac{t}{2}$

$K=3$ gives that $\frac{5t}{8} < q_1 < \frac{2t}{3}$

$K=4$ gives that $\frac{5t}{8} < q_1 < \frac{19t}{30}$

$K=5$ gives that $\frac{91t}{144} < q_1 < \frac{19t}{30}$

Now assign $a_K$ with the lower bound coefficient of $t$ and $b_K$ for the upper bounds and so :

$a_n = \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{91}{144} ,\cdots\}$ and $b_n = \{1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{19}{30},\frac{19}{30} ,\cdots\}$

I know that $ \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n$ , i thought first that it will converge to the golden ratio $0.618....$ but i know from the case $K=4$ that this is not the case .

So my question is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = ?$

Comment: From numerical testing it seems that the limit is $(1-\frac{1}{e})$.